# drop the view in sql server dynamically

Tags: sql

Below is code i want to delete view that is coming in a variable

```
declare @tbName nvarchar(max)
    set @tbName ='Vw_QueryBuilder_22viewcheckedmergedagain'
    exec('IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(' + @tbName + '))
    DROP VIEW ' + @tbName)
```

above code say view does not exist, but it exists i am able to show all records of the view

Comment: Does it help if you write it like `DROP VIEW dbo.' + ...`

Comment: no still it says "Invalid column name 'Vw_QueryBuilder_22viewcheckedmergedagain'.
"

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer it was quotes missing
i am sharing it may be any one can find it useful

```
declare @tbName nvarchar(max)
    set @tbName =N'Vw_QueryBuilder_22viewcheckedmergedagain'

    exec('IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @tbName + '''))
    DROP VIEW dbo. ' + @tbName)
```